# Using DAQmx with LabView on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, labview, nidaqmx

I'm working on a project that was created by a coworker, having been built on LabView on Windows. He used a bunch of DAQmx modules, but I'm having trouble opening them on my Mac.

I realize that DAQmx on the Mac is basically replaced with DAQmxBase - my question is if there's a simple way to switch from one to the other? Or would I need to go through and manually change each instance?

If it's the latter, is there any way to maintain consistency as we collaborate on the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch between the two APIs, you can use a [Conditional Disable Structure](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361M-01/glang/conditional_disable_structure/) and use the [`OS`](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361M-01/lvhowto/creating_cond_disable_struc/) symbol to change which API is used on each platform.

Note that NI-DAQmx Base is a subset of NI-DAQmx. There's a high likelihood that your colleague has chosen to use capabilities that aren't available on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have to manually change each VI.

There is a [conversion utility](http://www.ni.com/download/ni-daqmx-base-to-ni-daqmx-conversion-utility-1.0/446/en/) only to go from DAQmxBase  to DAQmx (but probably I would do it manually even in this case).